# PHP, echo $object;

Tags: исключения, php

Все привет.

Есть объект класса `City`. Если пишу

```
echo $city;
```

нет ни ошибок, ни записей в лог, ни исключений.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так?

```
$city = new City;

echo $city;
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: @Costa, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это у вас вывод ошибок видимо не стоит.

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7zOt4c)

Comment: Спасибо! Странно, ворнинги все идут и нотайсы, а на эту штуку вообще ничего...

Comment: В php ini стоял один e_strict.

Answer (score 0):

> echo -- Выводит одну или более строк

Для вывода объекта используй **print_r($city)** или **var_dump($city)**

Если хотите через echo, то в объекте нужно написать перевод в строковое значение:

```
public function __toString() { return "dsfsd"; }
```

Comment: Спасибо, это понимаю, непонятно, почему ошибка не срабатывает, ни в логах нет записей, ничего. Хотя всякие ворнинги идут.

Comment: @Costa, ясно ) вопрос не совсем понял значит )